# Implicit Validation Attributte

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a custom data type `Money` which I am creating server and client side validation for. Applying a custom validation attribute to each and every property in each and every view model is tedious. Is there a way I can set the validation attribute to all `Money` properties in one go?

Comment: do you want to apply the custom validation to just the Money types?

Comment: @DaveA yes all Money types

Comment: What kind of validation? range? required? both?

Comment: I want to validate that the value typed into the input can be parsed into a currency value.

Comment: Have you tried nesting validation in your Money definition?

Comment: Why not just reuse your money object in each viewmodel?

Comment: But I need to wire up the client side validation, hence the original need to apply an attribute.

Comment: I'm still missing something, help me out :) adding that object as essentially a viewmodel in each of your other viewmodels should automatically pick up its validation attributes. Why would this scenario not work? Maybe some code would help me here. Your custom attribute is applied at your money data type definition and if not possible wrap it in another viewmodel that you then use everywhere

Answer (score 1):

You could implement [IValidatableObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx) in Money type.

Then override the [Validate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.validate.aspx) method, to do all validations at one shot.

Here is an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_aspnetmvccustomvalidation_topic4.aspx)

Comment: No client side validation then though

Comment: @AdamTuliper-MSFT Nope, AFAIK. Not sure if MS included this in MVC4.

Comment: No it's still server side only by design, the OP though wanted client side.